# What is the area of the shaded region?

Tags: geometry, area

Problem 2 seems to have two ways of going about it.

**Way 1**

Assume the whole shape is a triangle and the unshaded region is a trapezoid. Subtract the trapezoid's area from the triangle's area.

**Way 2**

Assume both shaded regions are triangles. Add the shaded triangles' areas.

I'm fairly certain at least Triangle 1's area is correct because finding the area of the trapezoid containing Triangle 1 and the unshaded trapezoid yields the same area as when combining the area of Triangle 1 determined in Way 2 and the area of the trapezoid determined in Way 1: A=(a+b)*h/2 = ((12+13)+15)*11/2 = 220.

**Question**

Why doesn't Way 2 provide the correct answer?

[image]

Comment: How did you find the area of Triangle $1$?

Comment: base*height/2=> 13*11/2 = 71.5

Comment: the picture is deceptive. "hypotenuse" of the large "triangle" is not a straight line or maybe trapezoid is not a trapezoid. $25/32 \ne 15/21$

Comment: Put a ruler on the drawing and check if the big figure actually is a triangle.

Comment: @Patrick Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I would love to! But unfortunately he hasn't corrected the mistake in his answer that I pointed out in the comments on his answer. I don't have the privilege that allows me to @ mention CiaPan. Could you @ mention him in the comment section of his answer and maybe he'd respond?

Answer (score 3):

It's the second solution which is correct, and the first one is wrong!

The error hides in the assumption the whole figure is a triangle. If it was, the big triangle would be similar to the smaller one on the right side, hence the proportion would hold
$$\frac{12+13}{11+21}=\frac{15}{21}$$
However, it does not, as
$$\frac{12+13}{11+21}=0.78125 > 0.7142857 \approx \frac{15}{21}$$
and the big figure is a concave quadrangle.

Comment: But if the first one is wrong also the second should be since 15 is not the height.

Comment: Ah, I see your point CiaPan! But how can we be sure the 2nd solution is correct as you say? Doesn't the second solution assume that 15 is the height of the right triangle?

Comment: @Patrick If you don't assume the line segment described as `15 in` is perpendicular to the `11+21 in` base, you won't be able to calculate _anything_. You couldn't even say the triangle with base `13 in` has a height of `11 in`, because without the right angle the lines `15 in` and `12+13 in` would not be parallel...! Also the first approach would be flawed then, because with no parallel sides we couldn't say the white part is a trapezoid...

Comment: You're right. Remove the part of your answer that says the second solution is correct and I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You numerical calculation is correct, indeed for the first

- whole: $\frac12 \cdot 32 \cdot 25 =400$
- trapezium: $\frac12 \cdot (15+12) \cdot 11 = 148.5$

then $A=251.5$.

For the second

- triangle 1: $\frac12 \cdot 15 \cdot 21 = 157.5$
- triangle 1: $\frac12 \cdot 13 \cdot 11 = 71.5$

then $A=229$.

The discreapncy depends upon the fact that the given of the problems are wrong, indeed observe that the segment with length 15 is not orthogonal to the base indeed

$$\frac{15}{21}=\frac{5}{7}\approx 0.71423\neq \frac{25}{32}=0.78125$$

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, the question is, what's wrong with Way 2?

Comment: @Patrick You should explai how you calculate it. I don't see a sufficient number of information  at a first sight, you can obtain them but it is more complex.

Comment: If _'the segment with length 15 is not orthogonal to the base'_ then the white trapezium is NOT a trapezium, and you can't use $\frac 12\cdot (15+12)$ for a 'mean width'...

Comment: @CiaPan Yes of course, I indicated that the numerical calculation is correct but that there is some mistake in the set up of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first triangle is not a right triangle, so determining the base and height for the formula $A=\frac12(base)(height)$ is a little more delicate.

Indeed, for the base of triangle $1$, one needs to draw a right triangle with the base of triangle $1$ being the hypotenuse of the "new" triangle. Then we can calculate the base to have length:

$$
\sqrt{3^2+11^2}=\sqrt{130}.
$$

The height is a little more challenging since we don't know the angles of the given triangles, but the length of the third side can easily be calculated using a similar technique, and one can then apply [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to calculate the area of triangle $1$.

Comment: We can't assume the height is 11 so that won't work. But thanks for the link to Heron's formula. I learned something new!

Comment: @Patrick: The height is not $11$. The length of the bottom leg of the right triangle that we form *is* $11$ (this is **not** an assumption, but it is given to us by the length below the trapezoid).

Comment: Because we don't know if the line segment with a length of 15 in. is perpendicular to the bottom line segment, we can't say what the length is of bottom leg of the right triangle you're talking about. See CiaPan's answer and the comments on that answer for more explanation.